# sql select query in wordpress 'page'

Tags: query, sql

I want to run simple sql select query in wordpress 'page' without using php. I want to display a single row of database.

Comment: And how would you like to do this without PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a post row by the ID

```
global $wpdb;

$mylink = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = 10" );
```

Comment: "without using php"